# Quotes missing when saving json data inside a database (ajax related)

Tags: php, json, ajax

I noticed that I'm missing the usual quotes when using JSON data inside a database table. This only happens inside the second column `Followers IDs`

[image][image]

My code  is as follows:

```
public function ajax_follow_me() {

    check_ajax_referer( 'km-ajax-create-nonce', 'security' );   

    $current_user   = get_current_user_id();
    $target_user    = isset( $_POST['data-follow-user'] ) ? $_POST['data-follow-user'] : false;

    if( ! empty( $_POST['data-follow-user'] ) ) {           
        $this->follow_user( $current_user, $target_user );
    }   

    wp_die();   

}
```

Next step...

```
public function follow_user( $current_user = 0, $user_to_follow = 0  ) {

    if ( empty( $user_to_follow ) ) {
        return;
    }           

    $args = array(
        'user_id'   => $current_user,
        'follow_to' => $user_to_follow
    );

    $response = $this->add_following( $args );

    if ( ! empty( $response ) && $response !== FALSE ) {
        $args = array(
            'user_id'   => $user_to_follow,
            'followed_by' => $current_user
        );

        $this->add_followed_by( $args );

        $this->km_follow_me_success( $user_to_follow );

    } else {            
        $this->km_follow_me_error();
    }

}
```

First column:

```
    public function add_following ( $args = array() ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $author_info    = get_userdata( $args["user_id"] );

    if ( empty( $author_info->display_name ) ) {
        $author_name = $author_info->user_login;
    } else {
        $author_name = $author_info->display_name;
    }


    $defaults = array(
        'user_id'       => '',
        'follow_to'     => '',
        'username'      => $author_name,
        'user_email'    => $author_info->user_email
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    // First you have to check if the user already exists and return his Following Row       
    $following = array();

    $existing = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT following FROM {$this->table} WHERE user_id = %d", $args["user_id"] ) );

    if( ! empty( $existing ) ) {
        $following = json_decode( $existing, true );
    }

    // We check if this user ($args["user_id"]) is already following the $args["follow_to"] user.
    if( in_array( $args["follow_to"], $following ) ) {
        return TRUE;
    } else{
        array_push( $following, $args['follow_to'] );
    }


    // We verify if the user exists and update the value, if he does not and we sent username, then, we create it.
    if( null === $existing && ! empty( $args['username'] ) ) {
        $wpdb->insert( $this->table,
            array(
                'user_id'   => $args['user_id'],
                'username'  => $args['username'],
                'email'     => $args['user_email'],
                'following' => json_encode( $following ),
                'followers' => json_encode( array() )
            ),
            array( '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )
        );

        return $wpdb->insert_id;

    } else {

        $updated = $wpdb->update( $this->table,
            array(
                'following' => json_encode( $following )
            ),
            array( 
                'user_id' => $args["user_id"]
            ), 
            '%s', '%d'
        );

        return $updated;
    }

}
```

This code is for updating the second column (and where it's suppose to go wrong somewhere).

```
public function add_followed_by( $args = array()  ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $author_info    = get_userdata( $args['user_id'] );

    if ( empty( $author_info->display_name ) ) {
        $author_name = $author_info->user_login;
    } else {
        $author_name = $author_info->display_name;
    }

    $defaults = array(
        'user_id'       => '',
        'followed_by'   => '',
        'username'      => $author_name,
        'user_email'    => $author_info->user_email
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    // First you have to check if the user already exists and return his Followers Row
    $followers = array();

    $existing = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT followers FROM {$this->table} WHERE user_id = %d", $args["user_id"] ) );

    if( ! empty( $existing ) ) {
        $followers = json_decode( $existing, true );
    }

    // We check if this user ($args["user_id"]) is already followed by $args["followed_by"] user.
    if( in_array( $args['followed_by'], $followers ) ) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        array_push( $followers, $args['followed_by'] );
    }

    // We verify if the user exists and update the value, if he does not and we sent username, then, we create it.
    if( null === $existing && ! empty( $args['username'] ) ) {
        $wpdb->insert( $this->table,
            array(
                'user_id'   => $args['user_id'],
                'username'  => $args['username'],
                'email'     => $args['user_email'],
                'following' => json_encode( array() ),
                'followers' => json_encode( $followers )
            ),
            array( '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )
        );

        return $wpdb->insert_id;

    } else {

        $updated = $wpdb->update( $this->table,
            array(
                'followers' => json_encode( $followers )
            ),
            array( 
                'user_id' => $args["user_id"]
            ),
            "%s", "%d"
        );

        return $updated;
    }


}
```

Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get errors or is it just visual? Does it have another data type that may result in a cleaner view of the actual data?

Comment: It's just the difference between encoding an array of strings (which is what you're doing to create the first column) and encoding an array of integers (what you're doing to create the second column).

Comment: When storing json to your DB you might want to base64 it before. This way you avoid possible escaping errors and as a result also avoid SQL injection by user data

Comment: @Patrick Q: Care to give a hint on how to fix that? I'd like to keep both columns the same.

Comment: Without seeing the raw db data and and the un-redacted code, my initial tip would be that anything coming in on a request is treated as a string unless you cast it to something else. It is also somewhat unclear if this is happening when saving the data (that's my guess) or displaying the data. Your initial image appears to be some sort of admin/dashboard/report you have created, but the code for that doesn't seem to be included above.

Comment: It's definitely happening while saving the data. The image also reflects what is happening in the raw db (phpmyadmin) as well. I'll update my post to display the full code. :)

Comment: I used `var_dump` on both `$followers` and `$following` and it clearly says strings. `var_dump( wp_json_encode( $following ) );` results in `string(9) "["3","2"]" string(3) "[1]"`